# Copy i-value from array triple time

Tags: c, arrays

I have an `array[768]` but now I have only `256` (from `0` to `255`) samples in this array. I want to copy each value from `0` to `255` and fill this array better, I mean:

```
[1][2][3]  - >  [1][1][1][2][2][2][3][3][3]
```

How I can do that? Is there a library function that can do this?

Comment: Will you be modifying the array in place or creating a separate copy?

Comment: And what is the type of `array`'s elements?

Comment: I just want to copy values from array[256] to array2[768] :) Tried use for loop inside for loop but does not work for me.

Comment: Please post the code you wrote which attempted to do the work. We'll help you figure out why it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't recall any known library function capable of doing this.

If you want to do it in-place, I'd do it from right to left (i.e. tail to head), I *think* this is the only way to do it in-place:

```
int i, j;
for (i = 255, j = 767; i > 0; i--) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++) {
        array[j--] = array[i];
    }
}
```

If you don't need to do it in-place, this would suffice:

```
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 256; i++) {
    for (int k = 0; k < 3; k++)
        new_array[j++] = array[i];
}
```

Comment: Your code works ok! I tried like this:
`for(i=0,;i<3;i++){
 
 for(k=0;k<3;k++){
 
 tab2[k] = tab1[i];
 
 }
 
 
}`

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 768; ++i)
    new_array[i] = array[i/3];
```

The index of the right hand side of the assignment will vary only every three steps.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `i%256`? He said he's got 256 samples. And I think he wants a sample's copies to be contiguous, look at his example. This code would give you `[1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]` instead of `[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]`

Comment: @FilipeGonçalves uhm.. yes sorry, my fault. Actually the correct code is i / 3

Comment: Ah yeah, `i/3` will do it. That's neat. I hadn't thought of that.